# The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Object?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, dynamic, VxStatus?)'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
   VxBuilder(
  
     builder: (context, _) {
              return '\$${_cart.totalPrice}'
                  .text
                  .xl4
                  .color(Theme.of(context).accentColor)
                  .make();
            },
            mutations: {RemoveMutation},
          ),
```

[code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBzAg.png)

VxBuilder is having some issues when I upgrade it to 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/vxstate/latest/vxstate/VxBuilder-class.html) `VxBuilder` requires  `builder` as

```
Function(BuildContext context, T store, VxStatus? status)
```

Therefore you need to pass three parameters in `builder` constructor.